# TSQL - STSymDifference

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, spatial

The documentation states:

> Returns an object that represents all points that are either in one geography instance or another geography instance, but not those points that lie in both instances.

Given @g3

```
LINESTRING (-122.348 47.649, -119.119263 46.18363401)
```

And @g2

```
POINT (-119.119263 46.18363401)
```

Why is @g3.STSymDifference().STAsText()

```
LINESTRING (-122.348 47.649, -119.119263 46.18363401)
```

And not a single point (-122.348 47.649)?

Point -119.119263 46.18363401 is in both @g2 and @g3 and is not excluded.

Answer (score 1):

> Point -119.119263 46.18363401 is in both @g2 and @g3 and is not excluded.

Rounding.  The coordinate system has finite precision, so when you remove the endpoint from a line, what should the new endpoint be?

There's no great answer for that.  The length of the line doesn't change.

You get similar precision and rounding strangeness if you try to determine if a point is on a line.

EG

```
declare @g3 geography = geography::Parse('LINESTRING (-122.348 47.649, -119.119263 46.18363401)')
declare @g2 geography = @g3.STIntersection(geography::Parse('LINESTRING (-120.5 48, -120.5 46)'))

select @g3.STIntersection(@g2).STAsText()
```

outputs

```
GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to your example by converting the linestring to a series of points and comparing the point to that series. I hope this helps out.

```
DECLARE @LinestringGeometry GEOMETRY;
DECLARE @PointGeometry GEOMETRY;
SET @LinestringGeometry = GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING (-122.348 47.649, -119.119263 46.18363401)', 4269);
SET @PointGeometry = GEOMETRY::STGeomFromText('POINT (-119.119263 46.18363401)', 4269);

--Get series of points within the linestring
WITH GeometryPoints(N, Point) AS  
( 
   SELECT 1,  @LinestringGeometry.STPointN(1)
   UNION ALL
   SELECT N + 1, @LinestringGeometry.STPointN(N + 1)
   FROM GeometryPoints GP
   WHERE N < @LinestringGeometry.STNumPoints()  
)

--Compare the points
SELECT Point.STAsText() AS 'UniquePoint'
FROM GeometryPoints
WHERE Point.STEquals(@PointGeometry) = 0
```

Comment: This is not the answer I was looking for. However, your response contains a gem of a trick - your CTE neatly enumerates the points (sequentially) in a geography object.